# Update query using php mysqli_query (procedural style)

Tags: php

I am using this code to update rows and the value of $result is coming true. The if condition is executing. But the data in the table isnt updated. So, No errors yet the updation isnt happening.
What is the problem? Any help appriecated. :) Happy Diwali

```
 for($i=0;$i<$len-1;$i++){  
    $sqlquery="UPDATE items_data SET item_price='".$price[$i]."' WHERE item_name='".$items[$i]."'";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$sqlquery);
    if($result){
        echo "Working";
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysqli_error($connection);   
    }
}
```

Comment: if $len==1 the the query would not execute beacuse u are ending loop sth like $len-1 and in case $len==1 it would become 0 and no data will be updated

Comment: a positive `$result` doesn't say if the query was "effective", but only that the query was successfully executed without errors. Note, that a mysql-notice wouldn't throw an error though!

Comment: echo out $sqlquery and test it directly on db

Comment: you could also check for `mysqli_affected_rows()`

Comment: I tried mysqli_affected_rows. It gave the output as 0

Comment: the value of $len is 20+ always

Comment: I copied and pasted the sqlquery on phpmyadmin and ran it. It affected rows successfully

Comment: But, Not when I am doing it using PHP